# Upload Image Preview code created by Button doesn't preview the image. Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So basically i'm stuck.  I created a simple upload image button that allows me to preview the image file that i uploaded.  I also created a button that creates another upload image button the button is called "Try It".  My first upload image button, previews the image correctly, but when i push the "Try It" to create another upload image button and upload another image, it does not preview on the additional upload image button.  I just want to know how i can fix it.  Below is the full code:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
   x.type = "file";
   x.id= "file-upload"
   x.onchange= "previewFile()";
   document.getElementById("wtf").appendChild(x);
   var y = document.createElement('IMG');
   y.src= "";
   y.alt= "Image preview...";
   document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(y);
}
      
function previewFile(){
   var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
   var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
   var reader  = new FileReader();

   reader.onloadend = function () {
       preview.src = reader.result;
   }

   if (file) {
       reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
   } else {
       preview.src = "";
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="wtf">
      <input id="file-upload" type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
    </p>
    <p id="preview">
      <img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `element.onchange` takes a function and not a string i changed that also since you need to show different previews with different buttons you need a way to distinguish between them. I am creating a global variable `i` to keep track of it and passing it to the `previewFile` function as a parameter.

Here is the code:

```js
var i = 0;
function previewFile(index){
   var preview = document.querySelectorAll('img'); //selects the query named img
   var file    = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')[index].files[0]; //sames as here
   var reader  = new FileReader();

   reader.onloadend = function () {
       preview[index].src = reader.result;
   }

   if (file) {
       reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
   } else {
       preview.src = "";
   }
}

function myFunction() {
   i++;
   var y = document.createElement('IMG');
   y.src= "";
   y.alt= "Image preview...";
   y.height = 200;
   document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(y);
   var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
   x.type = "file";
   x.id= "file-upload"
   x.onchange= function(){previewFile(i)};
   document.getElementById("wtf").appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="wtf">
      <input id="file-upload" type="file" onchange="previewFile(0)">
    </p>
    <p id="preview">
      <img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you soo much i've been racking my brain trying to fix it.